# Handling per buildtype/flavor configuration in custom gradle plugin

Tags: gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

When writing a custom Gradle plugin, how is it possible to access the extension properties defined per buildtype/flavor in the consuming build.gradle?

I have the following extension class -

```
    TestExtension {
    String name;
    String address;

    // getters and setters

    };
```

Consumer of this gradle plugin would populate properties using closures as shown below  -

```
// default
Test {
   address = "default address"
}
android {
    buildTypes {
        release {
            Test {
                name = "release-mode"
            }
         }
        }
        debug {
            Test {
                name = "debug-mode"
            }
         }
    }
}
```

In the gradle plugin, I create and run a separate task for each buildtype. How do you access the right properties when specific task is run? For instance, I never get the right `name` property when releasetask is run. its always set to "debug-mode". 
Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

inside the `apply(Project project){}`-Method of your custom Gradle-Plugin (written in Groovy):

```
project.android.applicationVariants.all{ variant ->
    //do your variant specific code here
}
```